# call backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync() function for two functions one after other c# windowsform

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, windows-forms-designer

I want to call backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync() function for two functions one after other but I got this error :

> "This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently."

I know what's problem. Is there any way to do this? This is a sample from what I want to do, in fact there is many strings and many functions that one come after other.

If it's not possible    how can I create a windowsForm to show me my first String[] elements one by one in a label and when it's done start again and show my second string[] elements in same label?

```
public Form1() {
   InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   looking();
}

public void looking()
{
   a();
   b();
}

public void a()
{
   string[] stringArray = { "Ali", "Hasan", "Morad", "Javad" };
   backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(stringArray);
}

public void b()
{
   string[] stringArray2 = { "Ali2", "Hasan2", "Morad2", "Javad2", "Mahmood", "Shaparak" };
   backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(stringArray2);
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
   ...
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   ...
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: The only difference between `a()` and `b()` is the input to the `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` function. Why can't you just pass all the input in the same function, say, `a()`? For whatever reason that is not possible, you can just create 2 separate `BackgroundWorker` threads.

Comment: so how can I create a windowsForm to show me my first String[] elements one by one in a label and when it's done start again and show my second string[] elements in same label?

Comment: @MuhammadEhsanMirzaei what is your need exactly

Comment: @MuhammadEhsanMirzaei take a look at my updated answer

Comment: Taking your code literally, the smallest change would be to add a handler for the `RunWorkerCompleted` event and call `b()` in that handler. Other approaches include changing your `DoWork` handler to a method that takes both arrays as input, move the current `DoWork` code into a different method that takes a single array as input, and have the first method call the second, or to move to a pure `async`/`await` implementation (but not what was posted below...that example's not very good).

Answer (score 0):

using `Backgroundworker` is no more considered a good practice today. Take a look at [`async` and  `await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)
 in your case, you can try this

based on your update you can achieve this

```
 private  async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await lookingAsync();
        }

        public async Task lookingAsync()
        {
            string[] stringArray = { "Ali", "Hasan", "Morad", "Javad" };

            foreach (var item in stringArray)
            {

                    label1.Text = item;
                  await  Task.Delay(1000);                                 
            }
            string[] stringArray2 = { "Ali2", "Hasan2", "Morad2", "Javad2", "Mahmood", "Shaparak" };
            foreach (var item in stringArray2)
            {

                label1.Text = item;
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
              //if you want it in  a loop just uncomment this 
            // await lookingAsync();
        }
```